# How to pip freeze for different arch?

Tags: pip

How can I create a requirements file via `pip freeze` that's compatible for multiple architectures?
For example installing `pytorch` is different between Linux and OSX. Linux will include a bunch of `NVDIA CUDA/CUDNN` libraries. However these are not included in OSX. I would like to avoid having multiple frozen requirements files as I'm leveraging an install script for both local dev and CICD, as well as a job that automatically updates dependencies across multiple python projects.